# Android: Different permissions for different flavors

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have An app with tow flavors ... only one of them needs some permissions.
How can I request these permissions only for this flavor during building apk?

These are the permissions needed:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I assume that you have two product flavors, `chocolate` and `vanilla`. The `chocolate` one is the one that needs the additional permissions.

Step #1: In `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`, put the `<uses-permission>` elements that are in common between all the flavors

Step #2: Create `src/chocolate/`, a source set that will hold source that will only be used for `chocolate` builds, not `vanilla` builds

Step #3: In `src/chocolate/AndroidManifest.xml`, inside an otherwise-empty `<manifest>` element, put the `<uses-permission>` elements that `chocolate` needs that `vanilla` does not

Now, your `chocolate` builds will have all of the permissions, while `vanilla` builds will only have those from the `main` manifest.

Comment: I'll try this solution.

Answer (score 1):

For each flavor you have to define a manifest wich contains unsimilarities

Comment: Is this present by default or should I define them?

Comment: you should define them