# Removing permissions from manifest depending on build flavor

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I have 3 flavors and each of them should have a different permissions.
My flavors are defined like so:

```
  allPermissions {
        dimension "permissions"
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeCallLogPermission: "false", excludeSmsPermission: "false"]
    }

    noSmsPermission {
        dimension "permissions"
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSmsPermission: "true"]
    }

    noSmsNoCallogPermission {
        dimension "permissions"
        manifestPlaceholders = [excludeCallLogPermission: "true", excludeSmsPermission: "true"]
    }
```

and in my Manifest I have this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"
    tools:remove="${excludeCallLogPermission}"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
    tools:remove="${excludeSmsPermission}"/>enter code here
```

It doesnt give any errors and builds but the app has the 2 mentioned permissions even if the flavor sets both to false so it is not working.

If I try using tools:node="${excludeSmsPermission}" and set the value of it to remove I get this warning
[image: the warning]

Comment: For each flavor you have to define a manifest wich contains unsimilarities

Comment: here is the method https://stackoverflow.com/a/47145109/11647620

Comment: Sadly that approach doesn't work for my project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a hackish solution that works

```
allPermissions {
        dimension "permissions"
        manifestPlaceholders = [extraPermission1: "android.permission.SEND_SMS", extraPermission2: "android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"]
    }

    noSmsPermission {
        dimension "permissions"
        manifestPlaceholders = [extraPermission1: "android.permission.placeholder", extraPermission2: "android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"]
    }

    noSmsNoCallogPermission {
        dimension "permissions"
        manifestPlaceholders = [extraPermission1: "android.permission.placeholder", extraPermission2: "android.permission.placeholder"]
    }
```

and

```
 <uses-permission android:name="${extraPermission1}"/>
<uses-permission android:name="${extraPermission2}"/>
```